# Worklight Direct Update and user authentication

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-security

Is there any way to avoid that the log in screen appears after updating a Worklight application when the user is already authenticated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This scenario is not possible in Worklight 6.1

In Worklight 6.2, however, Direct Update will appear before any user authentication (as its default behavior - changeable). Therefore user authentication will be done only once.

Worklight 6.2 is expected to be released in June.